# Subset sum for a list with dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, subset-sum

Given `aList` as:

```
[
  {'name': 'Hailey', 'age': 20, 'id': 48479},
  {'name': 'John', 'age': 40, 'id': 18021},
  {'name': 'Asger', 'age': 18, 'id': 22281},
]
```

and a given target sum as `targetSum = 50`.

The problem is to look through `aList` with the key `age`, then remove elements from `aList` who's value for `age` cannot be combined to equal (approximately) `targetSum`. 
The elements that can be combined to equal to (approximately) `targetSum` should be retrievable by their `id` in a list.

Alternatively to avoid removing the elements, the problem is simply to find all possible combinations of the given elements which have an `age` attribute that sums up (approximately) to `targetSum`.

I have the function for finding a subset in a list to give sum. However the limitation is that it only takes a list of numbers so `[1, 2, 3, 4, ...]` instead of dictionaries.

```
def subsetInListForSum(numbers, target):
    results = []
    for x in range(len(numbers)):
        results.extend(
            [   
                combo for combo in combinations(numbers ,x)  
                    if sum(combo) == target
            ]   
        )   

    print(results)
```

Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: `len(numbers)` should be `len(1, numbers+1)`. Otherwise, `combinations(numbers ,x)` is nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will work as is, since aList is still a list. You just need to change the if condition to

```
   if sum(val['age'] for val in combo) == target:
```

This way your 'results' variable will consist of all combinations of the dictionary elements from aList for which age sums up to the target value.

Answer (score 0):

As your function works for a list, so just extract a list of ages from the list of dicts `aList`, and then use your function.

```
list_dicts = [{'name': 'Hailey', 'age': 20, 'id': 48479},
              {'name': 'John', 'age': 40, 'id': 18021},
              {'name': 'Asger', 'age': 18, 'id': 22281}]

list_ages = [d['age'] for d in list_dicts]

print(list_ages)
# Output
[20, 40, 18]
```